# SQLBulkCopy inserts a new row with NULL values for all columns

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I have this code which works fine and loads the excel data into an SQL table. The only problem is that it also inserts a new row with NULL values for all columns.

```
using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
excel_con.Open();
string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();
 using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(excelPath) + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }
            excel_con.Close();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.mySQLTable";


                    sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 200;

                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Employee", "Employee_Name");
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Sal/Hourly", "Sal/Hourly");

                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Total", "Total"); 

                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
}
```

This 2988 row is not present in excel, but the code creates it. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This seems a bit wrong. The name of the source table should be the sheet name (or a named range) `"SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]"`

Comment: excel file has only one sheet "sheet1" by default fot all files. so it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your query to skip empty rows in excel:

```
"SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(excelPath) + "] WHERE [Employee] IS NOT NULL"
```

This should avoid that empty rows are added to the `DataTable`. Of course you could also remove them later but it would be less efficient. For example:

```
dtExcelData = dtExcelData.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("Employee")))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Small manipulations can be done to remove that row or to add this where condition. I am in search of a concrete solution for this. Any property of SQLBulkcopy I may be missing or anything ?

Comment: @Sak your row *will* exist in Excel and in the `DataTable` you've filled. It often happens when you 'touch' a cell by editing and then deleting a value. This almost certainly isn't a problem with bulk copy - it will write what you give it.

Comment: @Sak: above is just a small modification of your own query. It should avoid that empty rows are added to the `DataTable`. Of course you could also remove them later but it would be less efficient. For example: `dtExcelData=dtExcelData.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("Employee"))).CopyToDataTable();`