# Horizontal scroll using shift + scroll in asp.net web application's Gridview?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a web application in asp.net, it has a gridview with more than 12 columns. I added a horizontal scroll bar using

```
 <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <asp:GridView ID="gvBill" runat="server" >
  .
  .
  </asp:GridView>
```

I need a functionality to horizontal scroll.. just the gridview. I have searched and found answers on mouseWheel event but they all are for c# Windows applications. 
I need same as we have in StackOverflow. Please give me some URLs or anything that can help. Thanks.

e.g : In SO when we hold Shift key and use Mouse scroll / TouchPad scroll, it scrolls horizontally. Try it here: [SQLBulkCopy inserts a new row with NULL values for all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880016/sqlbulkcopy-inserts-a-new-row-with-null-values-for-all-columns/37880112#37880112)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Gridview{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

and

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBill" runat="server" CssClass="Gridview" />.
```

will add a scroll to the x direction

Instead if you want to catch the mousewheel event i found this solution:

```
(function() {
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        document.getElementById('yourDiv').scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('yourDiv').addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.getElementById('yourDiv').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
        // Firefox
        document.getElementById('yourDiv').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        document.getElementById('yourDiv').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
    }
})();
```

basically when it loads the document it gets the id of your element and it add the listener to the scrollHorizontally...test it and let me know if it helps

source: [Horizontal scrolling with mouse wheel in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700927/horizontal-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel-in-a-div)

i've provided an jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lugj8dp2/
it seems to work with normal table, it should work in your case.

Comment: anyway i think that wrapping the gridview like you do should work...if it didn't work try setting a fixed width like this:
<div style="overflow-x:auto;width:800px"></div> around the GridView.

Comment: Will it work with just scroll using Touchpad/Mousewheel ? I dont see shift key mentioned anywhere.
The above fix did not work.

Comment: overflow-x:auto will just add a horizontal scroll bar which is happening. I need to scroll it with Shift or any hotkey + mouse scroll bar. I hope you got my question .

Comment: do you want to use ONLY the thouchpad/mouse wheel and disable the hor scrollbar?

Comment: No, Please try the same here. Go to the question's code details where you see a horizontal scrollbar then hold shift key + Scroll your mouse. I need the same functionality.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880016/sqlbulkcopy-inserts-a-new-row-with-null-values-for-all-columns/37880112#37880112

Comment: sorry for not having understood your question at first time

Comment: No problem. Ok, I see you edited answer.. Will try it in a while and reply. Thanks @Lorenzo

Comment: note that you can't use the gvBill id to attach event because of runat='server' you must get the result id that asp will generate

Comment: Thank you @Lorenzo. You helped me saving a lot of time. It does work on Shift+Scroll only on google chrome but not on IE and gives below error 
"Line: 185
Error: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: I have IE 11 version

Comment: Well I tried and it looks like Chrome does it by default. I removed the javascript and it still scroll horizontally by pressing Shift key.

Comment: what ie is trying to says is that he can't find the id you are writing, so as i sayd before look at the id the asp is giving to you because of runat server it will not give to you gvBill but something like MainContent_gvBill and as i sayd the browser should have done by itself