# How to import data from Excel to SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel, import, console

I have [this](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/xls-to-sql-vbnet-csharp.html) reference on how to import data from excel to SQL using C# Console. The problem is I am getting errors because of the html tags (not sure though, ex. ). Even if I have added the *Bytescout.Spreadsheet* Reference needed, still errors occur. Please help me to make this work.
https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/xls-to-sql-vbnet-csharp.html
Thank you so much.

Comment: Just remove the <span .... as the span doesnt end thats why its showing on screen

Comment: Why dont you use SSIS to do this or if you have to go through C# take a look at [npoi](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @BugFinder That was actually the issue. haha. thank you so much.

Comment: You could try this way , it works just fine.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880016/sqlbulkcopy-inserts-a-new-row-with-null-values-for-all-columns#comment63217796_37880016

Comment: @WilDech I can add it as an answer if you wish to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page has a small HTML error on it so as a result you just need to remove all the "" to the end of items that arent relevant to make code you can read.

such as "`using (<span data-scayt_word="SqlConnection" data-scaytid="17">SqlConnection</span> connection = new <span data-scayt_word="SqlConnection" data-scaytid="18">SqlConnection</span>(<span data-scayt_word="connectionString" data-scaytid="15">connectionString</span>)`" turns to

"`using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)`"

the latter of course is far more likely to work

Answer (score 0):

use import export wizard like this:

[image]