# How to check null/white space in Excel file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I have implemented following code for my project where I read data from Excel file
and insert into sql database using SqlBulkcopy.

I am now facing an issue in Excel file where somewhitespaces are being inserted at the end of the excel file ( after all data). When I insert these data into the system all the null values are being inserted.I am trying to read only data with out null so that My db will not have null values. If I use db operation for stopping null values , My sqlbulk copy stops working.

Kindly find the code below. If you notice this code "SELECT *FROM [Sheet1$]", I understand I have to check null here but no idea how it is.

```
public static string ExecuteBulkCopy(string connectionString, string TableName, string Paths)
        {

            SqlBulkCopy oSqlBulk = null;
            string error = null;
            OleDbConnection myExcelConn = new OleDbConnection
                   ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
                       "Data Source=" + Paths +
                       ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
            try
            {

                myExcelConn.Open();

                // GET DATA FROM EXCEL SHEET.
                OleDbCommand objOleDB =
                    new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] IS NOT NULL", myExcelConn);

                // READ THE DATA EXTRACTED FROM THE EXCEL FILE.
                OleDbDataReader objBulkReader = null;
                objBulkReader = objOleDB.ExecuteReader();

                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {

                    cn.Open();
                    oSqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString,SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers);

                    oSqlBulk.DestinationTableName = TableName; // TABLE NAME.
                    oSqlBulk.WriteToServer(objBulkReader);
                    // return 1;

                    //call the overload that takes a connection in place of the connection string
                    // return ExecuteNonQuery(cn, commandType, commandText, commandParameters);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                oSqlBulk.Close();
                oSqlBulk = null;
                myExcelConn.Close();
                myExcelConn = null;
            }
            return error;
        }
```

Comment: A couple of things need clarification.  First, when you say you're trying to avoid inserting nulls, are you trying to eliminate just the nulls at the end of the read, or individual null values in cells that are in other rows?  Second, what error do you get when it "stops working?"

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the nulls at the end of read. This is my first priority. In some cases, Some columns also having null values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLBulkCopy inserts a new row with NULL values for all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880016/sqlbulkcopy-inserts-a-new-row-with-null-values-for-all-columns)

Comment: those links doesn't answer my issues.Thanks